# when execute "from pyzbar import pyzbar" i got a WindowsError, Hope someone more knowledgeable can help. Thanks a lot

Tags: python, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

here's my code:

```
from pyzbar import pyzbar
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/qrx-tool/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyzbar import pyzbar
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\pyzbar.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .wrapper import (
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\wrapper.py", line 143, in <module>
    c_uint_p,    # minor
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\wrapper.py", line 136, in zbar_function
    return prototype((fname, load_libzbar()))
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\wrapper.py", line 115, in load_libzbar
    libzbar, dependencies = zbar_library.load()
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\zbar_library.py", line 60, in load
    dependencies, libzbar = load_objects(Path(__file__).parent)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\zbar_library.py", line 54, in load_objects
    libzbar = cdll.LoadLibrary(str(directory.joinpath(fname)))
  File "D:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 不是有效的 Win32
```

Comment: An imported DLL hasn't Win32 format. Probably your Python is 32 bit while the zbar DLL is 64 bit.

Comment: Agreed. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=WindowsError%3A+%5BError+193%5D&t=ffab&ia=web

Comment: i check the python version and it's 64 bit